# How to make a DateRangeFilter with Google Charts Laravel MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to show a PieChart with a DateRangeFilter of GoogleChart, but the console shows me an error that the column is not a type "date".

JS

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mes', 'Estado', 'Cantidad', 'Usuario', 'TestCase'],
    @foreach ($registros as $key => $value)
    ['{{ $value->fechaini }}', '{{ $value->estado }}', {{ $value->cantidad }},
    '{{ $value->usuario }}', '{{ $value->testcase }}'],
    @endforeach
]);

// Create a range slider, passing some options
var RangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'slider_div',
    'options': {
    'filterColumnLabel': 'Mes'
    }
});
```

Controller

```
$registros = DB::table('registros')
    ->select(DB::raw("estado, fechaini, usuario,  testcase,  count(*) as cantidad"))
    ->groupBy('fechaini', 'estado', 'usuario', 'testcase')

    ->get();
```

If I run this, Google Chart shows me "Column 0 is not a date" (and in my database is a date type). Is my error in the query or in the foreach?